# Good Tutorial For Lua and LÖVE

Tags: lua, love2d

I want to make a very simple 2D game, and have been reading a lot of good things about [LÖVE](http://love2d.org/), so I want to try it out. However I can't seem to find any good tutorials. The ones on the LÖVE page are rather unstructured, and the other one I found by Mathew Casperson is not very useful. Does anyone know of a better tutorial?

Comment: Interesting challenge: Read a game programming tutorial written for something like Flixel and translate it to LOVE/Lua to gain deep understanding. May require delving into source of Flixel/whatever.

Comment: @bearcdp: IMHO Flixel and Löve are too different from each other to easily translate a tutorial for one into the other.  For example, you don't have tilemaps and collision detection out-of-the-box in LÖVE as you do in Flixel.

Comment: @CeeJay That's where the interesting part comes in :) There's also tutorials and libs on love2d.org showing examples of how to roll your own tilemap.

Comment: Great resources on the official lua site, namely the reference manual: http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/ defiantly worth a read to get a great understand of lua, understanding tables in Lua are key!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Disclaimer: I've created the two tutorials I'm going to link here

I've done two tutorials. None of them is complete, but will get you from 0 to 80% quickly.

The first one is a LÖVE-centric one called love-tile-tutorial:

https://github.com/kikito/love-tile-tutorial

It's about 50% done. Starts with the basics, and deals with Images & Quads, as well as an introduction to Lua.

love-tile-tutorial is on hold at the moment, though - I'm doing other projects, such as the second tutorial.

The second tutorial concentrates in Lua itself - this is, not for LÖVE specifics, but for Lua in general; it actually works entirely from the console. It's a series of exercises for learning the language itself better. It's called Lua Missions:

https://github.com/kikito/lua_missions

I realize this is not exactly what you wanted (since not all LÖVE is covered), but I'm putting it here in case anyone finds it useful.

Answer (score 2):

I started using Lua and Löve a couple of weeks ago, I didn't find any good resource on getting started, I just used the [wiki](http://love2d.org/wiki/Main_Page), it covers the very basics and then you can just use the documentation for the rest. It's not very different from any other 2D graphics API out there.